# Insert Instant datetime into MySql database with millisecond precision in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, timestamp, java.time.instant

I am using `mysql 5.7.x` version. Also i am using java 8. I am trying to insert `java.time.instant` current datetime in millisecond precision into my mysql database from java code. For that I am using `preparedstatement`.

The table in my database is:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`timestamp` TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

My java code to insert  is:

```
    Instant instant = Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS);

    try (Connection conn = DbConnection.getCon();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test_table (timestamp) VALUES (?)");) {
        ps.setTimestamp(1, Timestamp.from(instant));
        ps.executeUpdate();
        LOG.info("Instant: {} and long: {}", instant, instant.toEpochMilli());
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

From my log, I can see instant with milliesecond as: 2019-07-30T10:52:34.865Z.
But in my mysql database it becomes: 2019-07-30 10:52:34.000Z

I have searched so many questions and answers in stack but none seems to work for me.

**Update 1:**

I tried using setObject as:

```
ps.setObject(1, Timestamp.from(instant));
```

But still same result. Cannot retrieve the milliseconds in database.

Comment: Huh, interesting question. Good code example; it seems like you're doing exactly everything right.

Comment: Stay away from the outdated `Timestamp` class. Use `ps.setObject(instant);` or `ps.setObject(instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC));`.

Comment: @OleV.V. thank you for the reply but then what should I place in mysql datatype?

Comment: Sorry, I was being unclear. `timestamp` is fine in the database. It's only the `java.sql.Timestamp` class that is pporly designed and outdated and which you don't want to use.

Comment: @OleV.V. the insert fails if I do that. setObject can be used but passing just instant, results in some format error.

Comment: My best guess is that the second form eorks, then. `atOffset` convetts to `OffsetDateTime`, which I expect to work (I hope we don't need a`LocalDateTime`).

Comment: i tried second one as well. Still same format error. But thank you, with setObject idea eventually led me to right answer.

Comment: Mind sharing the solution @UjjwalJungThapa?

Comment: yeap shared just now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL has `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function that can take long values inside and returns a representation of the unix_timestamp in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' or 'YYYYMMDDhhmmss.uuuuuu' format.
Reference from their manual here:
[FROM_UNIXTIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Since I have milliseconds since epoch, thus I have to use

> FROM_UNIXTIME(instant.toEpochMilli() * 0.001)

in my insert statement.

Yes nothing needs to be changed in database. The only things that are changed are in java code which are `setObject()` function used for `preparedStatement`, passing `instant.toEpochMilli()` as the argument there and finally use of `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function inside insert statement.

My final java code looks something like this:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS);

    try (Connection conn = DbConnection.getCon();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test_table (timestamp) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(?*0.001))");) {
        ps.setObject(1, instant.toEpochMilli());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        LOG.info("Instant: {} and long: {}", instant, instant.toEpochMilli());
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
```